# How to install eband_local_planner?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-hydro, move-base, eband-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I would appreciate it if someone can guide me on how to install eband_local_planner for use with move_base on Hydro because every approach that I have tried so far, has failed.

Thanks

---

---

I installed eband_local_planner by using the following commands:

```
rosws set eband_local_planner https://github.com/utexas-bwi/eband_local_planner --git
rosws eband_local_planner
roscd eband_local_planner
rosmake
```

**Running the command rospack plugins --attrib=plugin nav_core shows eband_local_planner loaded as a plugin but the eband_local_planner is installed in /home/powerbot67/ros/eband_local_planner/elp_plugin.xml
while the rest of the plugins are installed in /opt/ros/hydro/share. Could this be a problem?**

```
powerbot67@powerbot67-desktop:~$ printenv | grep ROS
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/powerbot67/ros/sbpl_lattice_planner:/home/powerbot67/ros/eband_local_planner:/home/powerbot67/hydro/sandbox:/opt/ros:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_WORKSPACE=/home/powerbot67/ros
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
ROS_DISTRO=hydro
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/hydro/etc/ros
```

I changed the move_base.launch file to use eband_local planner as follows:

```
<arg name="base_local_planner" default="eband_local_planner/EBandPlannerROS"/>
```

However, when I run move_base, I get the following error:

> [FATAL] [1455878479.341080841]: Failed
> to create the
> eband_local_planner/EBandPlannerROS
> planner, are you sure it is properly
> registered and that the containing
> library is built? Exception: Could not
> find library corresponding to plugin
> eband_local_planner/EBandPlannerROS.
> Make sure the plugin description XML
> file has the correct name of the
> library and that the library actually
> exists. [move_base-1] process has died
> [pid 5295, exit code 1, cmd
> /opt/ros/hydro/lib/move_base/move_base
> cmd_vel:=/RosAria/cmd_vel
> __name:=move_base __log:=/home/powerbot67/.ros/log/e58dae7e-d6f1-11e5-a32e-00026f87bbb1/move_base-1.log].
> log file:
> /home/powerbot67/.ros/log/e58dae7e-d6f1-11e5-a32e-00026f87bbb1/move_base-1*.log

Also, running roswtf gives the following:

```
ERROR Not all paths in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH [/home/powerbot67/ros/sbpl_lattice_planner:/home/powerbot67/ros/eband_local_planner:/home/powerbot67/hydro/sandbox:/opt/ros:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks] point to an existing directory: 
 * /home/powerbot67/ros/sbpl_lattice_planner
```

What should I do to solve this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227098/how-to-install-eband_local_planner?/) by [DanThe](https://answers.ros.org/users/24985/danthe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2016-02-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2016-02-19**:
ros version?

**Comment by [DanThe](https://answers.ros.org/users/24985/danthe/) on 2016-02-19**:
ROS version is Hydro

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-24**:
it looks like eband_local_planner is a catkin package. Why are you trying to build it with rosmake?

**Comment by [DanThe](https://answers.ros.org/users/24985/danthe/) on 2016-02-24**:
I am not sure when to use rosmake but your answer to my other question installed eband_local_planner successfully. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

eband_local_planner is marked as "released" on [its wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/eband_local_planner). This means that you should be able to install it from debs with:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-eband-local-planner
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DanThe](https://answers.ros.org/users/24985/danthe/) on 2016-02-24**:
Thank you!